# Remove legal entity check from some forms

Tags: dynamics-ax-2009, dynamics-ax-2012, axapta, ax

There are some forms which exist in only certain legal entities, I want to remove this check somehow, and make these forms available in some other legal entity as well, any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use country and region specific functionality to help meet the legal, regulatory, and business needs of individual geographies. A geography is any country or region that is identified by an ISO country or region code. In Microsoft Dynamics AX, you use **country region context** for this process.

### To set the CountryRegionCodes property

1. In the AOT, expand the Forms node.
2. Find and expand the form that contains the control you wish to make
   country-specific. Expand Designs, expand Design, and then add or
   find the control.
3. Right-click the control, and then click Properties. Use the
   Properties window to set the CountryRegionCodes property. You can
   add as many ISO codes as required via a comma-separated list.

   If the ISO code value of the CountryRegionCodes property does not match the ISO code value of the controlling party, the control is not displayed. If the values match, the control is displayed.
4. Right-click the form and click Save.

More can be find [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/hh404126.aspx).